# Adding the MATLAB CODER generated C in Android Studio

Tags: c, matlab, android-studio, matlab-coder

I have trouble in importing the generated code of matlab coder in android studio. Can someone help me in importing C?
[Screenshot of Folder with the .h and .c files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8cN4.png)

When Matlab generated the C code, it gave me a folder filled with .c and .h files but I don't know how to connect its input and output variables to my application. I already have the NDK and a sample .h file that shows Hello-jni! But I want to know how to use this C code from Matlab. Help. :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your entry-point functions have been generated in crop.h/c. The idea is to build the code with the NDK, invoke the functions declared in crop.h via JNI and that should work.

There's a demo video:

https://www.mathworks.com/videos/matlab-to-iphone-and-android-made-easy-107779.html

that shows integrating generated code into and iOS app and an Android app which I imagine should be helpful for getting oriented. The example using Eclipse with ADT rather than Android Studio.